# Problem with gb4e's spacing when using datatool

Tags: linguistics, datatool, gb4e

Say that I have a `.csv` file with sentences in [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), their glosses, and their translations that I want to incorporate into a document.

However, using `datatool` to loop over the `.csv` doesn't work with `gb4e`'s spacing macro, `\gll`.

Compare:

[image]

To:

[image]

I thought the problem might be putting the `\IPA` command inside a single `\textipa{}` command, but even the second version where the `\textipa{}` commands appear inside the `.csv` file rather than in the `\DTLforeach` loop leads to the same problem.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{glosses1.csv}
IPA,GLOSS,TRANSLATION
sonj2n-i motun kuki-lul an-m2k-ess-ta,boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC,The boy didn't eat every cookie
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{glosses2.csv}
IPA,GLOSS,TRANSLATION
\textipa{sonj2n-i} \textipa{motun} \textipa{kuki-lul} \textipa{an-m2k-ess-ta},boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC,The boy didn't eat every cookie
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{glosses1}{glosses1.csv}
\DTLloaddb{glosses2}{glosses2.csv}

\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\section{How it ought to look}

\begin{exe}
    \ex[]{\gll \textipa{sonj2n-i} \textipa{motun} \textipa{kuki-lul} \textipa{an-m2k-ess-ta} \\
    boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC \\
    \trans `The boy didn't eat every cookie'
    }
\end{exe}

\section{What it actually looks like}

\DTLforeach{glosses1}{%
\IPA=IPA,
\GLOSS=GLOSS,
\TRANS=TRANSLATION}{%
\begin{exe}
    \ex[]{\gll \textipa{\IPA} \\
    \GLOSS \\
    \trans `\TRANS'}
\end{exe}
}

\DTLforeach{glosses2}{%
\IPA=IPA,
\GLOSS=GLOSS,
\TRANS=TRANSLATION}{%
\begin{exe}
    \ex[]{\gll \IPA \\
    \GLOSS \\
    \trans `\TRANS'}
\end{exe}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `datatool`.  You can't pass a macro to `\gll` and have it separate the words inside the macro.

Comment: @AlanMunn Ah, right. That makes sense. Is there a way to force it to expand, then, before it gets passed to `\gll`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory this ought to work:

```
\DTLforeach{glosses2}{%
\IPA=IPA,
\GLOSS=GLOSS,
\TRANS=TRANSLATION}{%
\begin{exe}
\edef\doex{%
    \noexpand\ex[]{\noexpand\gll 
      \expandonce\IPA \noexpand\\
    \expandonce\GLOSS \noexpand\\
    \noexpand\trans `\expandonce\TRANS'}%
}
\doex
\end{exe}
}
```

However it seems there's a bug in `datatool` that's causing the first set of braces in `\textipa{sonj2n-i}` to be lost on loading the csv file. So the first entry is loaded as

```
\textipa sonj2n-i \textipa{motun} \textipa{kuki-lul} \textipa{an-m2k-ess-ta}
```

Instead of

```
\textipa{sonj2n-i} \textipa{motun} \textipa{kuki-lul} \textipa{an-m2k-ess-ta}
```

This can be fixed either by changing the column order or by inserting an empty brace:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{glosses2.csv}
IPA,GLOSS,TRANSLATION
{}\textipa{sonj2n-i} \textipa{motun} \textipa{kuki-lul} \textipa{an-m2k-ess-ta},boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC,The boy didn't eat every cookie
\end{filecontents*}
```

Or by inserting an empty column:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{glosses2.csv}
,IPA,GLOSS,TRANSLATION
,\textipa{sonj2n-i} \textipa{motun} \textipa{kuki-lul} \textipa{an-m2k-ess-ta},boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC,The boy didn't eat every cookie
\end{filecontents*}
```

I'll see if I can find out what's causing the bug. Here's the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{glosses2.csv}
,IPA,GLOSS,TRANSLATION
,\textipa{sonj2n-i} \textipa{motun} \textipa{kuki-lul} \textipa{an-m2k-ess-ta},boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC,The boy didn't eat every cookie
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{glosses2}{glosses2.csv}

\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\section{How it ought to look}

\begin{exe}
    \ex[]{\gll \textipa{sonj2n-i} \textipa{motun} \textipa{kuki-lul} \textipa{an-m2k-ess-ta} \\
    boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC \\
    \trans `The boy didn't eat every cookie'
    }
\end{exe}

\section{What it actually looks like}

\DTLforeach{glosses2}{%
\IPA=IPA,
\GLOSS=GLOSS,
\TRANS=TRANSLATION}{%
\begin{exe}
\edef\doex{%
    \noexpand\ex[]{\noexpand\gll 
      \expandonce\IPA \noexpand\\
    \expandonce\GLOSS \noexpand\\
    \noexpand\trans `\expandonce\TRANS'}%
}
\doex
\end{exe}
}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of document]

Comment: Thanks, Nicola! This is perfect for my purposes, at least, as the IPA column isn't the first column in my actual `.csv` file.