# Macro for expanding macro arguments to gb4e's \gll

Tags: linguistics, datatool, gb4e

This is a followup question to [Problem with gb4e's spacing when using datatool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210382/32888), where I was trying to loop over glosses stored in a CSV with `datatool` and print them with `gb4e`'s `\gll`. The issue was that I was passing macro arguments to `\gll` command, when it expects strings with spaces.

Nicola provided a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210448/32888) to my problem, which caused the macro arguments to `\gll` to be expanded before `\gll` saw them, so that it could handle the spacing appropriately.

Her solution was to create a macro, `\doex`, using `\edef`, inside the scope of the `\DTLforeach` command.

I now have reason to do this same thing inside multiple instances of `\DTLforeach`, so I'm wondering if there is a way to globally define the `\doex` command so that I don't have to redefine it each time I need to do this.

Ideally, it would be nice to be able to pass the column names to the `\doex` command, rather than have them hardcoded into the macro.

Here's a minimal **non**-working example that illustrates what I'm after. If possible, I'd also appreciate a little commentary explaining why this doesn't work and why your proposed solution does work. I'd like to better understand how macro expansion works with LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{glosses1.csv}
MyIpa,MyGloss,MyTranslation
sonj2n-i motun kuki-lul an-m2k-ess-ta,boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC,The boy didn't eat every cookie
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{glosses2.csv}
IPA,GLOSS,TRANSLATION
\textipa{sonj2n-i} \textipa{motun} \textipa{kuki-lul} \textipa{an-m2k-ess-ta},boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC,The boy didn't eat every cookie
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{glosses1}{glosses1.csv}
\DTLloaddb{glosses2}{glosses2.csv}

\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{gb4e}

% This doesn't work
\newcommand*{\doex}[3]{
  \noexpand\ex[]{\noexpand\gll 
  \expandonce#1 \noexpand\\
  \expandonce#2 \noexpand\\
  \noexpand\trans `\expandonce#3'}}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{glosses1}{%
\MyIpa=MyIpa,
\MyGloss=MyGloss,
\MyTranslation=MyTranslation}{%
\begin{exe}
  \doex{\MyIpa}{\MyGloss}{\MyTranslation}
\end{exe}
}

\DTLforeach{glosses2}{%
\IPA=IPA,
\GLOSS=GLOSS,
\TRANS=TRANSLATION}{%
\begin{exe}
  \doex{\IPA}{\GLOSS}{\TRANS}
\end{exe}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add an abstraction layer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{glosses1.csv}
MyIpa,MyGloss,MyTranslation
sonj2n-i motun kuki-lul an-m2k-ess-ta,boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC,The boy didn't eat every cookie
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{glosses2.csv}
IPA,GLOSS,TRANSLATION
\textipa{sonj2n-i} \textipa{motun} \textipa{kuki-lul} \textipa{an-m2k-ess-ta},boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC,The boy didn't eat every cookie
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{glosses1}{glosses1.csv}
\DTLloaddb{glosses2}{glosses2.csv}

\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\newcommand*{\doex}[3]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\ex[]{%
      \noexpand\gll 
      \expandonce#1 \noexpand\\
      \expandonce#2 \noexpand\\
      \noexpand\trans`\expandonce#3'%
    }%
  }\x
}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{glosses1}{%
\MyIpa=MyIpa,
\MyGloss=MyGloss,
\MyTranslation=MyTranslation}{%
\begin{exe}
  \doex{\MyIpa}{\MyGloss}{\MyTranslation}
\end{exe}
}

\DTLforeach{glosses2}{%
\IPA=IPA,
\GLOSS=GLOSS,
\TRANS=TRANSLATION}{%
\begin{exe}
  \doex{\IPA}{\GLOSS}{\TRANS}
\end{exe}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Easier with `xparse`, of course.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{glosses1.csv}
MyIpa,MyGloss,MyTranslation
sonj2n-i motun kuki-lul an-m2k-ess-ta,boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC,The boy didn't eat every cookie
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{glosses2.csv}
IPA,GLOSS,TRANSLATION
\textipa{sonj2n-i} \textipa{motun} \textipa{kuki-lul} \textipa{an-m2k-ess-ta},boy-NOM all cookie-ACC NEG-eat-PST-DEC,The boy didn't eat every cookie
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\DTLloaddb{glosses1}{glosses1.csv}
\DTLloaddb{glosses2}{glosses2.csv}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\doex}{mmm}
 {
  \adamliter_doex:VVV #1 #2 #3
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \adamliter_doex:nnn
 {
  \ex[]{\gll #1 \\~ #2 \\~ \trans `#3'}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \adamliter_doex:nnn { VVV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{glosses1}{%
\MyIpa=MyIpa,
\MyGloss=MyGloss,
\MyTranslation=MyTranslation}{%
\begin{exe}
  \doex{\MyIpa}{\MyGloss}{\MyTranslation}
\end{exe}
}

\DTLforeach{glosses2}{%
\IPA=IPA,
\GLOSS=GLOSS,
\TRANS=TRANSLATION}{%
\begin{exe}
  \doex{\IPA}{\GLOSS}{\TRANS}
\end{exe}
}

\end{document}
```

The `~` (spaces) after `\\` are essential for `\gll` to work.